# R Making each graph unique colour whilst in a loop

Tags: r, loops, graph

Note: If you would like to repeat my code you will need to download the SMfSB package from CRAN. However, I do not think that this is necessary to answer my question.

I have this code

```
cl <- rainbow(18)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="Time", ylab="Number of prey",xaxt='n', xlim=c(0, 
300), ylim=c(0, 1500), main="Caldrat")
for(i in seq(from=50, to=200, by=50)){
  for(k in seq(50,200,50)){
    LV$h =  function (x, t, th=c((k/100)*1,(i/100)*0.005,0.6)) 
    {
      with(as.list(c(x, th)), {
        return(c(th[1] * x1, th[2] * x1 * x2, th[3] * x2))
      })
    }
    out = gillespied(LV,T=30,dt=0.1)
    M1  = matrix(out[,1])
    for(j in 1:5){
      out=gillespied(LV,T=30,dt=0.1)
      M1 = cbind(M1,out[,1])
    }
    a =matrix(rowMeans(M1))
    lines(a, lwd="1.5", col = cl[i/25])
  }
}
axis(side = 1, at = (0:30)*10 , labels = 0:30)
legend("topright", legend=c("0.005/0.5", "0.005/1","0.005/1.5","0.005/2", "0.01/0.5","0.01/1","0.01/1.5","0.01/2","0.015/0.5","0.015/1","0.015/1.5","0.015
/2","0.02/0.5","0.02/1", "0.02/1.5","0.02/2"), lty =c(rep(1)), 
lwd=c(rep(1)), 
ncol=3, title ="Value of th2/th1", col=cl[1:17], cex=0.4)
```

And basically it produces 16 lines onto the same plot, each line being a mean value for when I change my variables (th1,th2). I, however, would like to have all 16 plots in unique colours, but I am struggling to do this as I have a loop function inside a loop function.

From my code you can see that for each i I repeated it 4 times for different values of k, and when I plot this I get 16 graphs buts only 4 colours (ie a colour for each value of i).

I was wondering if I could get some help on this matter. The graph is below in a link as I do not have enough reputation to post the graph straight away. Thanks.

GRAPH: https://gyazo.com/da5b83f8bc04a3437557b292e19e8643

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
 col = cl[i/25*4+k/25]
```

some extra comments:

- Your example is not reproducible
- put functions outside of loops
- your j loop seem to be very ineffective, you do not even have j in it, try doing it differently.
- 16 colors will not help, the eye cannot distinguish more than 6-8 on a graph. try using 4 different types of lines instead?
- you could also do the inelegant way of making a new variable which will get a +1 each time you add a line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. Just to answer some of you points. 1) I have downloaded a package which allows me to use these functions, as it's part of a project I'm doing. 2) It would effect my functions if I put them outside the loop as the function gillespied depends on LV which is in the loop function. 3) My j loop is in there as I want to repeat the system 5 times then take the mean, not just running it 1 time. 4) This is a really good point thank you, I'll look into that, but I'm not sure as to how I'll go about it. 5) I don't get what this point means, could you elaborate thanks

Comment: 1. if you want us to help, it is best to give a reproducible example, then only could I maybe understand remarks 2 and 3.

Comment: 5. instead of "lines(a, lwd="1.5", col = cl[i/25])":

    lines(a, lwd="1.5", col = cl[xx/25])
    xx=xx+1

Comment: Ok I see your point, in future I'll try to do a reproducible example if possibl. You mention before about using different type of lines to distinguish each graph from one another. However the issue I had with this is that they're not very clear either. Do you have any idea on how to distinguish 16 graphs?

Comment: maybe try to see whether you could not use plot_ly to make it interactive such that you can see only part of the figure at once. Another solution is to make 3 (or more) different plots.

Comment: I'll try the plot_ly method that you said, but I would like all the graphs on the same axis. This is because I'm trying to compare the means on the system when changing the rate parameters